# Why the the return address of "obj_addr" from "lobstr" package is different to the pointer address?

Tags: r

I have written a very simple R package that returns the pointer of integer values in R:

R code wrapper:

```
getAddrss = function(expandMat)
{
   result <- .C("pointer2", address = expandMat)
}
```

C++ code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <R.h>
#include <string>
#include<iostream>

extern "C"
{

void pointer2(int* address)
{

    std::cout<< "Memory Address: " << address <<std::endl;
    std::cout<< "Value: " << address[0] <<std::endl;
}
}
```

However, the memory address returned with the above function is different to the "obj_addr" from "lobstr" package.

Example:

```
library(lobstr)
library(myRPackage)
x=3:5
> obj_addr(x)
[1] "0x7f0e416562a8"
> getAddrss(x)
Memory Address: 0x7f0e41655c98
Value: 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `int*` here. However, an R `integer` vector is not a C `int` (even a vector of length 1). As described in [R Internals](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#SEXPs):

> What R users think of as variables or objects are symbols which are bound to a value. The value can be thought of as either a `SEXP` (a pointer), or the structure it points to, a `SEXPREC`... [which is] a C structure containing the 64-bit header as described above [and] three pointers (to the attributes, previous and next node).

You can actually see this with the `lobstr` package:

```r
x  <- 1L
lobstr::sxp(x)
# [1:0x7fffda8ee400] <INTSXP[1]> (named:5)
```

An `INTSXP` is one of 24 possible types. See [R Internals](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#SEXPTYPEs) for the other `SEXP` types and the fields included.

To get the pointer to the R object, rather than an `int`, you need to take an `SEXP` argument. This is exactly what `lobstr` does. The C++ [source](https://github.com/r-lib/lobstr/blob/d9ea7fb56632590f66bc4cb41f0d0a97875607c1/src/utils.h#L4) for `obj_addr_()` (which is the function ultimately called) is:

```c
inline std::string obj_addr_(SEXP x) {
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << static_cast<void *>(x);
  return ss.str();
}
```

As this function is called by another C++ function it can return `ss.str()`, which is a C++ `std::string` object. However, in our case, we want to return the memory address as a [character vector](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Handling-character-data) to R:

> R character vectors are stored as `STRSXP`s, a vector type like `VECSXP` where every element is of type `CHARSXP`... You can obtain a `CHARSXP` by calling `mkChar` and providing a null-terminated C-style string.

Creating an R character vector from `std::string` could (and generally should) be done very simply using [`Rcpp::StringVector`](https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/working-with-Rcpp-StringVector/). However, as this abstracts away some details of creating an `SEXP` that are worth showing, I will avoid it here, instead casting our `std::string` to a `char` array and using [`mkChar()`](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Handling-character-data).

We can use the [`inline`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/inline/index.html) R package to compile some code which returns a one-element character vector of the memory address:

```r
get_pointer  <- inline::cfunction(sig = c(x = "integer"),
    body = '
    // Get the pointer to the SEXP like lobstr
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << static_cast<void *>(x);

    // Convert the std::string to char array
    std::string addr_str = ss.str();
    char* addr_chr = new char[addr_str.length() + 1];
    strcpy(addr_chr, addr_str.c_str());
    
    // Create a character vector of length 1
    SEXP addr = PROTECT(allocVector(STRSXP, 1));
    // Cast addr_chr to CHARSXP as set it to the first element
    SET_STRING_ELT(addr, 0, mkChar(addr_chr));
    // For the garbage collector - see Advanced R
    UNPROTECT(1);    
    return addr;
    ',
    includes = "#include <sstream>"
)
```

This function returns the same value as `lobstr::obj_addr()`:

```r
x  <- 1L
lobstr::obj_addr(x) # "0x7fffc74eb368"
get_pointer(x) # "0x7fffc74eb368"

x  <- 1:10
all(sapply(x, \(x) identical(lobstr::obj_addr(x), get_pointer(x)))) # TRUE
```

### Resources for reading about R's C interface

I found these useful:

1. [R Internals](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#SEXPTYPEs) - the guide to the internal structures of R and coding standards for the core team working on R itself.
2. The [vectors](https://github.com/hadley/r-internals/blob/master/vectors.md) chapter of Wickham's R Internals Github repo.
3. [R's C Interface](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/C-interface.html#c-data-structures) chapter of Advanced R by Hadley Wickham.

In the final link, Wickham states:

> I do not recommend using C for writing new high-performance code. Instead write C++ with Rcpp. The Rcpp API protects you from many of the historical idiosyncracies of the R API, takes care of memory management for you, and provides many useful helper methods.

However, this was [written in 2014](https://github.com/hadley/adv-r/commit/397c15bb2ab58ef8464d1890a22ee86f95ae8fe1#diff-8af1a70831745434268821a95d976e53165f2749d458e6813e0297d2342b4382L31). Interestingly, in 2020, `dplyr v1.0.0` was released and the changelog [stated](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/news/index.html#vctrs-1-0-0):

> `dplyr` dropped its two heaviest dependencies: `Rcpp` and `BH`. This should make it considerably easier and faster to build from source.

The `dplyr` devs seem to have accepted, though, that optimising build time may have a slight performance cost. This is discussed [here](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/03/dplyr-1-0-0-is-coming-soon/). Ultimately it's important, I think, to have a sense of how R objects exist in C, but my impression is that the vast majority of package developers prefer the abstraction of `Rcpp` rather than dealing directly with R's C interface.